# Python constructor that initialize its parameters based on values from another python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns

I have a class `A` and its constructor takes many variables. In my project, these variables are identified from another python file, `B`.

file `B` looks like this:

```
p1 = 4
p2 = 1
...
pN = 'dd'
#and a bunch of other variables.
```

Class `A` looks like this:

```
class A():
   def __init__(p1,p2,...,pN):
```

The number of parameters included in the constructor of `A` is very high, and I don't think it would be easy for a user (i.e., another one who wants to use my class) to initiate. However, I want my class to be generic and decoupled from other files in the project (i.e., file `B`). My question is how class `A` should be constructed?

A solution in my mind would be to pass the name of the python file that defines the parameters to a constructer in `A`:

```
class A():
   def __init__(self,python_filename):
       self.p1 = python_filename.p1
       self.p2 = python_filename.p2
   def __init__(self,p1,p2,...,pN):
```

My first thought is to make a class in `B` that has static members, would that be a good design in terms of being pythonic and object-oriented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps modules are the answer.

If you have information in "B.py", you can "import B" to then use everything inside B. You could then write B.p1 to access the variable inside. You could import other files as B to do the same thing.

Here's a useful reference: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

You might also think about doing something like this which does module injection: [Python - 'import' or pass modules as parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689355/python-import-or-pass-modules-as-parameters)

so you can make a class like in that answer and just pass it in to access the variables inside without dependency on B.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, module=None):
        if not module:
            import module
        self.module = module
```